# ssis 2008 fuzzy lookup never finish but package execution completed

Tags: ssis

There is a package at my place that uses a fuzzy lookup. When I run the package in BIDS, it stops at the fuzzy lookup but strangely it also says package execution completed. Note at the bottom of the pic below, it says the package execution completed, but the conditional split and the following components didn't get executed. Help?

[image]

The fuzzy lookup config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the package debug option to run in 64 bit runtime. To do this, right click on your package name in the solution explorer, under "configuration properties" go to debugging. Change the Run64BitRuntime option to true.

If you are using the stock excel destination, you will need to change that to something else or use something other than the fuzzy lookup, as that will not work on 64 bit. Alternatively, load the fuzzy lookup results to a stage table, and push those in a separate package (or project) to the excel destination.